# Locating Certificates by Application Policy OID

Tags: c#, .net, security, x509certificate2

I have two x509Certificates installed in my Personal certificate store and wish to retrieve the certificates by Application Policy.

I use the following code to achieve this:

```
public X509Certificate2 LocateCertificate(Oid oid)
{
    var store = new X509Store(Store.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    try
    {
        var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByApplicationPolicy, oid.Value, true);
        if(certificates.Count != 1)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException(string.Format("Expected one certificate, found {0}", certificates.Count);
        }
        return certificates[0];
    }
    finally
    {
        store.Close();
    }
}
```

When both installed X509Certificates have different Extended key Usage values the above method successfully retrieve the correct certificate when provided with a valid OID. However, if one certificate does not have its Extended Key Usage property set it is also returned by the query along with the correct certificate. I want to guard against returning certificates which have:

1. An incorrect Extended Key Usage value set.
2. No Extended Key Usage value set.

Any help would be appriciated.